# How to create an anonymous object with property names determined dynamically?

Tags: c#, anonymous-types, dapper

Given an array of values, I would like to create an anonymous object with properties based on these values.  The property names would be simply `"pN"` where `N` is the index of the value in the array.

For example, given

`object[] values = { 123, "foo" };`

I would like to create the anonymous object

`new { p0 = 123, p1 = "foo" };`

The only way I can think of to do this would be to to use a `switch` or `if` chain up to a reasonable number of parameters to support, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to do this:

```
object[] parameterValues = new object[] { 123, "foo" };
dynamic values = null;

switch (parameterValues.Length)
{
    case 1:
        values = new { p0 = parameterValues[0] };
        break;
    case 2:
        values = new { p0 = parameterValues[0], p1 = parameterValues[1] };      
        break;
    // etc. up to a reasonable # of parameters
}
```

*Background*

I have an existing set of methods that execute sql statements against a database.  The methods typically take a `string` for the sql statement and a `params object[]` for the parameters, if any.  The understanding is that if the query uses parameters, they will be named `@p0, @p1, @p2, etc.`.

Example:

```
public int ExecuteNonQuery(string commandText, CommandType commandType, params object[] parameterValues) { .... }
```

which would be called like this:

```
db.ExecuteNonQuery("insert into MyTable(Col1, Col2) values (@p0, @p1)", CommandType.Text, 123, "foo");
```

Now I would like to use [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) within this class to wrap and expose Dapper's `Query<T>` method, and do so in a way that would be consistent with the existing methods, e.g. something like:

```
public IEnumerable<T> ExecuteQuery<T>(string commandText, CommandType commandType, params object[] parameterValues) { .... }
```

but Dapper's `Query<T>` method takes the parameter values in an anonymous object:

```
var dog = connection.Query<Dog>("select Age = @Age, Id = @Id", new { Age = (int?)null, Id = guid });
```

leading to my question about creating the anonymous object to pass parameters to Dapper.

---

Adding code using the `DynamicParameter` class as requested by @Paolo Tedesco.

```
string sql = "select * from Account where Id = @p0 and username = @p1";
dynamic values = new DynamicParameter(123, "test");
var accounts = SqlMapper.Query<Account>(connection, sql, values);
```

throws an exception at line 581 of Dapper's SqlMapper.cs file:

```
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
```

and the exception is a `SqlException`:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@p0".

and checking the `cmd.Parameters` property show no parameters configured for the command.

Comment: yeah, you are misusing DynamicParameter, see line 243: http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/source/browse/Tests/Tests.cs

Comment: also, `IDynamicParamters` gives you absolute flexibility. For dappers benefit you should never need to bake anon-types, as a learning experience you sort of can, but it is not worth the effort. In particular you can bake a strong type from an ICollection if you really wanted using emit.

Answer (score 15):

You are misusing Dapper, you should never need to do this, instead either implement `IDynamicParameters` or use the specific extremely flexible `DynamicParameters` class.

In particular:

```
string sql = "select * from Account where Id = @id and username = @name";
var values = new DynamicParameters();
values.Add("id", 1);
values.Add("name", "bob");
var accounts = SqlMapper.Query<Account>(connection, sql, values);
```

`DynamicParameters` can take in an anonymous class in the constructor. You can concat `DynamicParameters` using the `AddDynamicParams` method.

Further more, there is no strict dependency on anon-types. Dapper will allow for concrete types as params eg:

```
class Stuff
{
   public int Thing { get; set; }
}

...

cnn.Execute("select @Thing", new Stuff{Thing = 1});
```

Kevin had a similar question: [Looking for a fast and easy way to coalesce all properties on a POCO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422861/looking-for-a-fast-and-easy-way-to-coalesce-all-properties-on-a-poco) - `DynamicParameters` works perfectly here as well without any need for magic hoop jumping.

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly an anonymous object, but what about implementing a [DynamicObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx) which returns values for p1 ... pn based on the values in the array? Would that work with Dapper?

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class DynamicParameter : DynamicObject {

    object[] _p;

    public DynamicParameter(params object[] p) {
        _p = p;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result) {
        Match m = Regex.Match(binder.Name, @"^p(\d+)$");
        if (m.Success) {
            int index = int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value);
            if (index < _p.Length) {
                result = _p[index];
                return true;
            }
        }
        return base.TryGetMember(binder, out result);
    }

}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        dynamic d1 = new DynamicParameter(123, "test");
        Console.WriteLine(d1.p0);
        Console.WriteLine(d1.p1);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, thanks, this is great but unfortunately Dapper doesn't like it :(.  It ends up trying to execute the db command without any parameters at all -- not sure why yet, but I think it is trying to evaluate the `DynamicParameter` instance as a parameter value.

Comment: @adrift: can you post a small code sample that shows your problem?

Comment: edited the question to include code showing the exception generated when trying to use `DynamicParameter`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot dynamically create anonymous objects. But Dapper should work with dynamic object. For creating the dynamic objects in a nice way, you could use [Clay](http://clay.codeplex.com/). It enables you to write code like

```
var person = New.Person();
person["FirstName"] = "Louis";
// person.FirstName now returns "Louis"
```