# Dynamic property name as string

Tags: c#, azure, dynamic, azure-cosmosdb

When creating a new document with DocumentDB, I would like to set the property name *dynamically*, currently I set `SomeProperty`, like this:

```
await client.CreateDocumentAsync("dbs/db/colls/x/" 
   , new { SomeProperty = "A Value" });
```

, but I would like to get the `SomeProperty` property name from a string so that I can access different properties using the same line of code, like this:

```
void SetMyProperties()
{
    SetMyProperty("Prop1", "Val 1");
    SetMyProperty("Prop2", "Val 2");
}

void SetMyProperty(string propertyName, string val)
{
    await client.CreateDocumentAsync("dbs/db/colls/x/" 
       , new { propertyName = val });
}
```

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: [Dynamic Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491849/how-to-create-an-anonymous-object-with-property-names-determined-dynamically)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx) type (which was [introduced as part of the DLR](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/10/01/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject.aspx)) seems close to what you are describing. It can be used both as a dynamic object and as a dictionary ([it actually is a dictionary behind the scenes](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Actions/ExpandoObject.cs,43359e26c0f0e671)).

Usage as a dynamic object:

```
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
expando.SomeProperty = "value";
```

Usage as a dictionary:

```
IDictionary<string, object> dictionary = expando;
var value = dictionary["SomeProperty"];
```