# Dynamic mapping of properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I am interested if there is any way to dynamically map or add a child's object properties to the parent? For example, I have the following classes:

```
public class Parent {
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child {
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I will need to send from the back-end to the front-end in the following format:

```
public class Dto {
 public int ParentId { get; set; }
 public string ParentName { get; set; }
 public string Child1Name { get; set; }
 public string Child2Name { get; set; }
 public string Child3Name { get; set; }
}
```

keeping in mind that the parent can have a different number of children objects.I need this information in this format because it will be displayed in a grid (see image below). Can something like this be achieved and how?

[image]

Comment: You could use the `ViewBag` which is `dynamic`, but you would still need to enumerate in the view because there is a variable amount of children. You may be better off mapping your `Children` collection to a dictionary, with  `Child.Id` as the key and `Child.Name` as the value.

Comment: I highly recommend you to add an array to your dto with all child names included.

Comment: You can see the problem with this design on the first (title) row already if you look at it sequentially: even without having looked at the data yet, you somehow need to know that some of the parents will have 4 children. Do you have the front-end in place already and is it unchangeable? Does it expect JSON? You could look into a custom serializer, but more info is needed. You [could use an ExpandoObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661643/dynamic-property-name-as-string) which you cast to a dictionary where the keys are the property names, but then just use a dictionary anyway.