# Get modified object from client and combine it with an orginal object on the server

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

For example, I have this class

```
class Person{
    private int _id = int.MinValue;
    private string _name = string.Empty;
    private int _age = int.MinValue;
    private string _city = string.Empty;

    public string Id{ get { return _id ; } set { _id = value; } }
    public string Name{ get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }
    public int Age{ get { return _age; } set { _age = value; } }
    public string City{ get { return _city ; } set { _name = city; } }
}
```

and a list of Person that I show in a table. In this table there is an "edit in place/inline": some Person's property has a cell(td) in the table, so when I edit a cell, via javascript/jquery, I create the json object with the changed value and I send it to server. The json object contains only the property changed: if i edit "Name" the json object will be:

```
{"obj":{"Id":"1","Name":"Anna"}}
```

But the object Person to the server comes as

```
Id = 1, Name = "Anna", Age = 0, City = null
```

*So the problem is*: to execute an update stored procedure I must create the object with all original values ​​to exceptions of the modified property. In this example, i want get this object:

```
Id = 1, Name = "Anna", Age = 25, City = "New York"
```

To create this object I use this method

```
public static TEntity CopyTo<TEntity>(this TEntity OriginalEntity, TEntity NewEntity){
    PropertyInfo[] oProperties = OriginalEntity.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo CurrentProperty in oProperties.Where(p => p.CanWrite))
    {
         if (CurrentProperty.GetValue(OriginalEntity, null) == null)
         {
             CurrentProperty.SetValue(OriginalEntity, CurrentProperty.GetValue(NewEntity, null), null);
         }
    }

        return OriginalEntity;
}
```

If new object `Person` has a property with `null` value then I take the orginal value from the original `Person` (`NewEntity`). This way doesn't work with number because from client to server the `Age` property become `0` and not `null`.

How I can to resolve this problem? To consider that I can not use:

- nullable type because I should to modify so many lines of code in the whole project;
- the table may not contain all the properties of Person, so I can't create the entire object in javascript and then to change only the value modified.

I hope I was clear enough with my bad english

Comment: but if all properties of a person are editable in that table, then all of those values should be sent, regardless of all of them being changed or not. What I mean to say is, even if user changes only the name, your JS function should send all the other editable value in that row. Can you not modify your JS like that?

Comment: If you don't change to `Nullable<T>`, I can't see any sensible way of distinguishing between an *intentional* 0, and a "not set" 0. Frankly, sometimes the right thing to do is to change code.

Comment: I was hoping for some workaround...creative solution ;)

Comment: @Shades88: because in some cases, for example, there might be a class with 20 property but only 5 of these can be displayed in the table. In this case, How I can to create to entire object in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

k; if I re-phrase: you want to copy all properties that have non-null values onto an existing object. Well, the first issue (as you note) is that you can't have an `int` that is `null`. Fortunately, you can fix that by simply taking the pragmatic step of making `Age` and `Id` a `Nullable<int>`, aka `int?`:

```
class Person
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

So now we just have the "copy all non-null values". For *that*, look at [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422861/looking-for-a-fast-and-easy-way-to-coalesce-all-properties-on-a-poco), which is a bit like your reflection approach, but it uses IL to be stupidly fast.

Example usage:

```
var orig = new Person {Id = 1, Name = "Anna"};
var delta = new Person {Id = 1, Age = 25, City = "New York"};

var merged = Merger.Merge(orig, delta);
Console.WriteLine(merged.Id);
Console.WriteLine(merged.Age);
Console.WriteLine(merged.Name);
Console.WriteLine(merged.City);
```

It could also be tweaked to do an in-place merge over one of the existing objects.

Comment: As I wrote in my original messagge, I can't use a Nullable type because I get this exception "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. ":  I can't modify every line of code that use Person and all other object/class that can be modified through "edit in line"

Comment: @Webman then how do you propose to distinguish between "legal" and "illegal" uses of any value?

Comment: For example, I was looking for a way to use a big negative number..but i think that is not possibile