# how easily copy struct to a class if all fields are the same?

Tags: c#

I have `struct` like that

```
public struct InstrumentDefinition2
{
    public int instrumentId;
    public int Decimals;
    public long MinPriceIncrement_Mantissa;
    public short MinPriceIncrement_Exponent;
    public long RoundLot_Mantissa;
    public short RoundLot_Exponent;
    public char MsgType;        // 'd' - Security Definition 'f' - Security Status?
}

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public delegate void InstrumentReplayCallback(ref InstrumentDefinition2 value);
```

It constructed from this c++ struct via delegate call:

```
typedef struct _InstrumentDefinition {
    int32_t instrumentId;
    int32_t Decimals;
    int64_t MinPriceIncrement_Mantissa;
    int16_t MinPriceIncrement_Exponent;
    int64_t RoundLot_Mantissa;
    int16_t RoundLot_Exponent;
    char MsgType;        // 'd' - Security Definition 'f' - Security Status
} InstrumentDefinition;
```

It works fine. I'm not sure if I can declare InstrumentDefinition2 as a `class`. But I like declaring `InstrumentDefinition2` as `struct`, i'm thinking about it as about "pointer to c++ block of memory".

But during processing I need to copy it to a class. So I want to declare very similar `C#` class:

```
public class InstrumentDefinition
{
    public int instrumentId;
    public int Decimals;
    public long MinPriceIncrement_Mantissa;
    public short MinPriceIncrement_Exponent;
    public long RoundLot_Mantissa;
    public short RoundLot_Exponent;
    public char MsgType;        // 'd' - Security Definition 'f' - Security Status?
}
```

And the question is how can I copy `InstrumentDefinition2` struct to `InstrumentDefinition` class? Of course I can assign all fields one by one but it would:

- I guess relatively slow
- error-prone (what if new field is introduced and I forgot to add "coping" of it?)

So can I do that somehow without coping every single field?

Comment: Have you considered the use of an `AutoMapper` ?

Comment: @simsim no, I don't know what is it.

Comment: It lets you copy values from one class to another automatically , rather than assigning them manually, this approach is perfect if you have a lot of classes to be mapped together

Comment: You might be able to use a class instead of a struct for the P/Invoke. Have you tried that? Many of my P/Invokes just use classes even though the `C/C++` is using a struct on the other end. (If you do that, you need to remove the `ref`)

Comment: Maybe there could be a faster-than-reflection way like Mark Gravell has shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7423243/694852) (involves on-the-fly code emitting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to copy field or property values of class instances by matching names, you could use this snippet:

```
public void ShallowCopyValues<T1, T2>(T1 firstObject, T2 secondObject)
{
    const BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public;
    var firstFieldDefinitions = firstObject.GetType().GetFields(bindingFlags);
    IEnumerable<FieldInfo> secondFieldDefinitions = secondObject.GetType().GetFields(bindingFlags);

    foreach (var fieldDefinition in firstFieldDefinitions)
    {
        var matchingFieldDefinition = secondFieldDefinitions.FirstOrDefault(fd => fd.Name == fieldDefinition.Name &&
                                                                                  fd.FieldType == fieldDefinition.FieldType);
        if (matchingFieldDefinition == null)
            continue;

        var value = fieldDefinition.GetValue(firstObject);
        matchingFieldDefinition.SetValue(secondObject, value);
    }
}
```

This code uses reflection to determine the fields that have the same name and same type. If a match is found, the value is updated on the second object. Besides: this code is slower than assigning the values one by one, but this should not matter as normally classes do not have a large number of fields, which results in nearly no performance loss.

Consider this code being not complete. In production code, I would definitely recommend a library like Automapper (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper#readme) that is much more flexible and configurable, as mentioned by simsim.

Also, you can map C# classes to C++ structures by having the same layout, as mentioned by Mathew Watson. You just apply the `StructLayoutAttribute` to the class like it is shown in this example on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/795sy883.aspx The important thing is that the class in C# has the same memory layout as your struct has in C++.

Comment: it's too complicated and likely too slow. I just want to copy one block of memory to another block of memory....

Comment: I don't think there is another way of doing this. The managed runtime enforces type safety and thus you cannot just copy a block of memory from one position to another like in native C/C++. If you want to prevent copying from the structure to the class instance, than map the class directly, as I mentioned in the last paragraph.

Comment: but structures are passed by value in c#, so c# copies block of memory from one structure to another. I just need to do the same but for struct-class, not for struct-struct.

Comment: Unlike in C++, class instances are always on the managed heap in the CLR, so if you want to copy from a struct to a class, this always involves the heap.

Comment: Actually I just did a small performance check: two classes with the same two properties (one int, one string). One million assignments took around 15ms with direct assignment and ca. 1000ms with reflection mechanism on my computer. So if you have a large number of assignments, use direct assignments. You can even write a T4 template for this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb126445.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

For automatic fields/properties value copying, I'd use [Automoapper](http://automapper.org/), [Value injecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) or something similar.
In your case, copying values using value injecter would look like this:

```
instrumentDefinition.InjectFrom(instrumentDefinition2);
```

assuming variable names correspond to class and struct names.

Comment: even if they don't, you can still modify the mapped fields through the definition of the map

Comment: can I do the same without using extra libraries, i.e. using pure c#?

Comment: yes, via reflection, listing all fields from one type, looking for corresponding fields in other type and setting value. I doubt it's worth writing it on your own, better keep DRY and use library.

Comment: Have a look at Matthew Watson comment, maybe that's the right approach to eliminate the need of copying values problem...